# I want to print each word and respective occurrence of that word/element in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to print the amount of occurences of a character or word in a list.

'''
Python code
'''

```
list_elem=['a','x','e','x','i','x','o','x','u']

count_of_element=list_elem.count('x')

print("Count of a particular element in the list is : ",count_of_element)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

list_elem = ['a','x','e','x','i','x','o','x','u']

c = Counter(list_elem)

for k, v in c.items():
    print(f"Count of {k} element in the list is : {v}")
```

which outputs:

```
Count of a element in the list is : 1
Count of x element in the list is : 4
Count of e element in the list is : 1
Count of i element in the list is : 1
Count of o element in the list is : 1
Count of u element in the list is : 1
```

Comment: The above for loop doesn't work for me. Instead this work-                                           
for k, v in c.items():
    print("Count of {} element in the list is : {}".format(k,v))

Comment: @AbhishekBhushan, because your Python version is tad older. (Nevermind).

Answer (score 0):

Iterate each item in the list and check if it is equal to the item to find. count the equalities

```py
def count(list_elem_to_find, lst):
    count_of_item = 0
    for item in lst:
        if item == list_elem_to_find:
            count_of_item += 1
    return count_of_item
list_elem=['a','x','e','x','i','x','o','x','u']
count_of_x = count('x', list_elem)
print("Count of x in list: " + str(count_of_x))
```